# Provisioner local-exec is giving invalid command in Terraform Apply Stage

Tags: azure, terraform

I am provisioning infrastructure on Azure with Terraform via Azure DevOps Pipeline

I am using below snippet as part of code to approve private end point once its created

```
  resource "null_resource" "azurecli_syn_approve_pe_adf_01" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {

   # interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
   # interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
   # Trying Powershell as interpreter
   interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
   working_dir = "${path.module}"

  # https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13573
  command = <<EOT
      az login --service-principal --username $(aad_login_sp_app_id) --password $(aad_login_sp_password) --tenant $(aad_login_tenant_id)
      synId=$(az storage account show -n $storageAccountName --query "privateEndpointConnections[2].id" -o tsv | tr -d '\r\n')
      echo "APPROVING |"$synId"|"
      az storage account private-endpoint-connection approve --id $synId --description "Approved by Terraform"
  EOT

  environment = {
    storageAccountName = "${azurerm_storage_account.syn_ws_sa.name}"
    resourceGroup = "${azurerm_resource_group.syn_rg.name}"
    aad_login_sp_app_id = "${var.aad_login_sp_app_id}"
    aad_login_sp_password = "${var.aad_login_sp_password}"
    aad_login_tenant_id = "${var.aad_login_tenant_id}"
  }
  }

  depends_on = [
    time_sleep.wait_50_seconds
  ]
}
```

Error I am getting is:

```
│ or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
│ included, verify that the path is correct and 
│ try again.
│ At line:1 char:53
│ + ... az login --service-principal --username $(aad_login_sp_app_id) --pass
│ ...
│ +                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
│     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (aad_login_sp_app_id:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
│     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
│  
│ aad_login_sp_password : The term 'aad_login_sp_password' is not recognized
│ as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
│ file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
│ included, verify that the path is correct 
│ and try again.
│ At line:1 char:87
│ + ... ame $(aad_login_sp_app_id) --password $(aad_login_sp_password) --tena
│ ...
│ +                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
│     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (aad_login_sp_password:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
│     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
│
```

Please suggest where I am missing syntax, I checked indentation all looks good.

Updated: My Varibles.tf looks like below

```
variable "resource_group" {
  type = string
}

variable "location" {
  type = string
}

variable "prefix" {
  type = string
}

resource "random_string" "postfix" {
  length = 6
  special = false
  upper = false
}

variable "aad_login_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "aad_login_tenant_id" {
  type = string
}

variable "aad_login_object_id" {
  type = string
}

variable "jumphost_username" {
  type = string
}

variable "jumphost_password" {
  type = string
}

variable "synadmin_username" {
  type = string
}

variable "synadmin_password" {
  type = string
}

variable "enable_syn_sqlpool" {
  type = string
  description = "Variable to enable or disable Synapse Dedicated SQL pool deployment"
}

variable "enable_syn_sparkpool" {
  type = string
  description = "Variable to enable or disable Synapse Spark pool deployment"
}

variable "aad_login_sp_password" {
  type = string
}

variable "aad_login_sp_app_id" {
  type = string
}
```

and I populate/pass these values from terraform.tfvars.json via a File transform/Substituion task

```
{
  "aad_login_name": "",
  "aad_login_tenant_id": "",
  "aad_login_object_id": "",
  "enable_syn_sparkpool": "",
  "enable_syn_sqlpool": "",
  "jumphost_password": "",
  "jumphost_username": "",
  "location": "",
  "prefix": "",
  "resource_group": "",
  "synadmin_password": "",
  "synadmin_username": "" ,
  "aad_login_sp_app_id": "",
  "aad_login_sp_password": ""  
}
```

and

my transformed variable value coming properly when i print values i get like below

```
{
    "aad_login_name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aad_login_tenant_id": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    "aad_login_object_id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx",
    "enable_syn_sparkpool": "true",
    "enable_syn_sqlpool": "true",
    "jumphost_password": "***",
    "jumphost_username": "azureuser",
    "location": "australiaeast",
    "prefix": "syn",
    "resource_group": "terraformdemo07",
    "synadmin_password": "***",
    "synadmin_username": "pocsqladmin",
    "aad_login_sp_app_id": "***",
    "aad_login_sp_password": ***
}
```

Comment: it seems something messed up with variables. Is it possible to share your variables.tf file

Comment: Hi @TapanHegde updated my original post with varaibles.tf and tfvar file content

Comment: @TapanHegde I guess You got the issue, like you pointed the last variable not getting quotes   for password variable in above json substitution, strange that all setup was right earlier re created same variable in azure and re ran to test it, now it substitute correctly, need to check if actual local exec provisional logic works or not. shall update